# Let A and B be square matrices of same order. Are the characteristic polynomials of AB and BA same? A and B may be invertible or not.

Tags: linear-algebra

If A or B are invertible than I am able to prove that characteristic polynomials of AB and BA are same. But in second case I am sticking.