# Relation between the minimal polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

If we have $A$ a $n$ by $m$ matrix and $B$ a $m$ by $n$ matrix, then is there a relation between the minimal polynomial of $AB$ and the one of $BA$, like in the case of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: For the case $m=n$, this has been answered several times in the past. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651592/

Comment: For the non-square case, see the answer by user164626 to the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342